# Is there any way to see the resulting github action job definition after evaluating the matrix and any github expressions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am creating dynamic GitHub workflow jobs using the matrix and a variety of GitHub expressions throughout the job.

A simple, non-matrix, example:

```
jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      type: ${{ steps.type.outputs.type }}
    steps:
      - id: type
        name: Identify run type
        run: |
          case "${{ github.ref_name }}" in
            main) echo "type=apply" >> "${GITHUB_OUTPUT}";;
            *)    echo "type=plan" >> "${GITHUB_OUTPUT}";;
          esac
  deploy:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.type == 'plan' && 'test' || 'deploy' }}
    steps:
      - run: echo "Running ${{ needs.setup.outputs.type }}!"
```

When looking at the `deploy` job output, I can see the output from the steps, but not the evaluation of the environment name or other GitHub expressions that might exist in the job definition.  Since the steps won't be executed if the dynamic evaluation causes the job definition to be invalid for some reason, it would be nice to be able to see the results of that dynamic evaluation of the job definition.

Is there any way to obtain the job definition with all expressions evaluated?

In the example above, I'd be looking for:

```
  deploy:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: test
    steps:
      - run: echo "Running plan!"
```

Comment: Wait a minute. After all, your code is just working as intended.
I've just checked it on GH and after a slight obvious fix (adding "runs-on:" statement and "run:" command in step) the whole thing works fine -> according to the case github.ref_name condition. Running on the main branch results "Running apply!" and "Running plan!" on other branch.

Comment: Yes, it works fine.  My point is, I want to be able to _see_ what the evaluation of the job definition is, so I can _see_ the evaluated environment name and evaluated step commands and etc., so _if there was a failure_, I could see what caused the failure.

Comment: (Edited to add missing runs-on: and run: entries)